# Unity problem when i convert playerprefs save to the standard file io save

Tags: c#, datetime, unity-game-engine, encryption, save

i am using tow kind of save the main save which is encrypting save that is using in this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XOjd_qU2Ido&t=351s) and playerprefs save 
when i use them together with the playerprefs only works when i disable the playerprefs the encrypting save work how to make them work together
 the playerprefs comes as cs script when i bought daily reward from the asset store
this the cs script that contain the playerprefs
so i got a problem when i convert playerprefs save to the standard file io save  any help to convert it to the unity io save

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;

namespace NiobiumStudios
{
    /**
    * Timed Rewards Canvas is the User interface to show Timed rewards
    **/
    public class TimedRewards : DailyRewardsCore<TimedRewards>
    {
        public DateTime lastRewardTime;     // The last time the user clicked in a reward
        public TimeSpan timer;
        public float maxTime = 3600f; // How many seconds until the player can claim the reward
        public bool isRewardRandom = false;     // Is the reward random or the player chooses from available rewards?

        public List<Reward> rewards;

        public delegate void OnCanClaim();              // When the player can claim the reward
        public OnCanClaim onCanClaim;

        public delegate void OnClaimPrize(int index);   // When the player claims the prize
        public OnClaimPrize onClaimPrize;

        private bool canClaim;              // Checks if the user can claim the reward

        // Needed Constants
        private const string TIMED_REWARDS_TIME = "TimedRewardsTime";
        private const string FMT = "O";

        void Start()
        {
            StartCoroutine(InitializeTimer());
        }

        // Initializes the timer in case the user already have a player preference
        private IEnumerator InitializeTimer()
        {
            yield return StartCoroutine(base.InitializeDate());

            if (base.isErrorConnect)
            {
                if(onInitialize!=null)
                    onInitialize(true, base.errorMessage);
            }
            else
            {
                LoadTimerData();

                if(onInitialize!=null)
                    onInitialize();

                CheckCanClaim();
            }
        }

        void LoadTimerData ()
        {
            string lastRewardTimeStr = PlayerPrefs.GetString(GetTimedRewardsTimeKey());

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(lastRewardTimeStr))
            {
                lastRewardTime = DateTime.ParseExact(lastRewardTimeStr, FMT, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                timer = (lastRewardTime - now).Add(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(maxTime));
            }
            else
            {
                timer = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(maxTime);
            }
        }

        protected override void OnApplicationPause(bool pauseStatus)
        {
            base.OnApplicationPause(pauseStatus);
            LoadTimerData();
            CheckCanClaim();
        }

        public override void TickTime()
        {
            base.TickTime();
            if(isInitialized)
            {
                // Keeps ticking until the player claims
                if (!canClaim)
                {
                    timer = timer.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Time.unscaledDeltaTime));
                    CheckCanClaim();
                }
            }
        }

        public void CheckCanClaim ()
        {
            if (timer.TotalSeconds <= 0)
            {
                canClaim = true;
                if (onCanClaim != null)
                    onCanClaim();
            }
            else
            {
                // We need to save the player time every tick. If the player exits the game the information keeps logged
                // For perfomance issues you can save this information when the player switches scenes or quits the application
                PlayerPrefs.SetString(GetTimedRewardsTimeKey(), now.Add(timer - TimeSpan.FromSeconds(maxTime)).ToString(FMT));
            }
        }

        //Returns the TimeRewardsTime playerPrefs key depending on instanceId
        private string GetTimedRewardsTimeKey()
        {
            if (instanceId == 0)
                return TIMED_REWARDS_TIME;

            return string.Format("{0}_{1}", TIMED_REWARDS_TIME, instanceId);
        }

        // The player claimed the prize. We need to reset to restart the timer
        public void ClaimReward(int rewardIdx)
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetString(GetTimedRewardsTimeKey(), now.Add(timer - TimeSpan.FromSeconds(maxTime)).ToString(FMT));
            timer = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(maxTime);

            canClaim = false;

            if (onClaimPrize != null)
                onClaimPrize(rewardIdx);
        }

        public string GetFormattedTime()
        {
            if(timer.Days > 0) 
                return string.Format("{0:D2} days {1:D2}:{2:D2}:{0:D3}", timer.Days, timer.Hours, timer.Minutes, timer.Seconds);
            else
                return string.Format("{0:D2}:{1:D2}:{2:D2}", timer.Hours, timer.Minutes, timer.Seconds);
        }

        // Resets the Timed Rewards. For debug purposes
        public void Reset()
        {
            PlayerPrefs.DeleteKey(GetTimedRewardsTimeKey());
            canClaim = true;
            timer = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0);

            if (onCanClaim != null)
                onCanClaim();
        }

        // Returns a reward from an index
        public Reward GetReward(int index)
        {
            return rewards[index];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use PlayerPrefs to store game state. That's not what it was designed for, don't use it for that, stop. Unity has standard File IO available. Use it.

Comment: @Draco18s that's the problem the asset come with this save i want to convert it the standard file io how can i do that for this script

Comment: Find everywhere PlayerPrefs is used, remove it, and use standard File IO (`System.IO.File`)

Comment: @Draco18s can you rewrite as the answer because i got some error using it like there's no GetInt in systm.io.file and this my first time using it i will make sure to put  answer mark thanks

Comment: You need to serialize things. This means using json, similar, or writing your own system. Unity comes with JsonUtility, though it can't handle certain things. Tutorials exist for both writing to a file and using json.